# How to name the connection to Wi-Fi?

Tags: windows-8

On one of my computers, I've got the name as supposed to. But on the other, despite the fact that it's recognized as *ChamsterNet*, when I connect to it, it get's the name *ChamsterNet 2*. All's working just fine but that annoys me so terribly...

How do I get rid of it?!

I suspect that it's got to do with the fact that I Reinstalled the firmware on the router. So, I think I'd like to clear the cache of all the networks ever found. Where can I do that? I've tried *forgetting* that network (the one with 2 in the name) but it keeps re-popping.

[image]

EDIT:

Right now, it looks like this. (Sorry for the Swedish.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to forget ChamsterNet. Since Windows thinks it's seeing a different network with an identical SSID, it's appending the 2. Getting rid of ChamsterNet "1" and ChamsterNet2 should fix this annoyance.

Comment: But how?! When I forget ChamsterNet 2, the old Chamster Net appears **but** when I conenct to it, it shows as ChamsterNet 2 again...

Comment: Did you forget both of them? There should be two.

Comment: Nope, I only saw one. And even more weird - now I'm connected to *ChamsterNet*, it's displayed as *ChamsterNet 2* **but** none of them displays among the networks in *Manage wireless networks*! What's happeninig?! How do I forget **everything** and start over?!

Comment: Actually, maybe this will better exemplify my problem. See the second image in my question (just updated it).